# Simple Injector: How do I implement an interface in multiple classes?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I have an interface: `IJobEngine` that I want to implement in class `JobEngineA` and `JobEngineB`.

How do I register this in Simple Injector?

Currently in `ConfigureServices`, I have:

```
services.AddSingleton<IJobEngine, JobEngineA>();
```

Do I simply add:

```
services.AddSingleton<IJobEngine, JobEngineB>();
```

And - if so, when injecting `IJobEngine`, how do I specify which implementation to use?

Comment: How do you want to decide what goes where? what are the conditions

Comment: I agree with Michael. You need to provide us with more context for us to be able to answer your question.

Comment: https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html#collections ?

Comment: @grek40 - I think this may be what I'm looking for, but those collections seem to be collections of three services that do different things.. Steven/Michael - basically I have two JobEngines that run jobs.  There is an old one and a new one.  I have a jobEngineID that we can use to delineate one from the other.  Does that help?

Comment: Shoe some more code. How is this id passed? Where does it come from? How should it be used?